# Roblox Script Help: userinputservice if statement stops movement if pressed while stationary

Tags: lua, roblox

i know the title is probably extremely confusing but i have a problem, im making a run script that whenever you press the left control key, your walkspeed changes, this works well when you are already moving but whenever you have control held down while stationary and try moving, you cant until control is let go of,

Script:

```
local char = script.Parent
local hum = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local cam = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(key)
    print("input recived")
    if key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftControl then
        print("left control iput recived")
        cam.FieldOfView = 98
        hum.WalkSpeed = 22
    end
end)
UIS.InputEnded:Connect(function(key)
    print("input recived")
    if key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftControl then
        print("left control iput ended")
        cam.FieldOfView = 90
        hum.WalkSpeed = 12
    end
end)
```

i havent tried anything yet, i want the character to move while control is pressed, even if pressed while not moving